# What command can I use to insert the current directory in the command-line mode?

Tags: command-line

Currently, I set the following keymap to my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <C-z> :NERDTreeToggle ~/Dropbox/jupyter/<CR>
```

However, I sometimes want to trigger it with different directory, for example:

```
:NERDTreeToggle CURRENT_DIR
```

However, I tried the following command [with the following answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8233/vim-get-current-directory), but it did not work.

```
:NERDTreeToggle getcwd()
:NERDTreeToggle pwd
```

How can I get the current directory to insert into the command-line mode?

Comment: Interactively, use the `=` expression register with control r

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I just came back to this question to add that to my answer! Goodjob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments you pass to a command are used as text, not as expressions, so unless a command specifically evaluates the expression in its implementation, passing an expression such as `getcwd()` won’t function how you’re hoping.

Instead, you can write a command where the expression is evaluated before being passed to the argument:

```
:execute 'NERDTreeToggle' getcwd()
```

You might need to add a bit more handling for paths that contain spaces to stop them being passed as separate arguments:

```
:execute 'NERDTreeToggle' escape(getcwd(), ' ')
```

Alternatively, you can use the expression register to add the result of a function directly. While in command-line mode press <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> and then type your function `getcwd()` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
:NERDTreeToggle .
```

is doing what you're looking for -- several other commands work this way `:sp`, `:e`...

If you want to use `getcwd()`, you would have needed to play with `:execute`, or `c_CTRL-R_=` in that case. I prefer the later when I can (from mappings, or from the command-line e.g.).

```
nnoremap µ :NERDTreeToggle <c-r>=getcwd()<cr><cr>
```

Interactively, this means you'd have to type CTRL+R and conclude with ENTER, twice.

If your question was *"the directory from the current file"*, interactively I usually type  `CTRL+R % CTRL-W` (^W once or twice depending `.` is in the `&isk` list or not). In a mapping/script/..., instead of `getcwd()`, I call `expand('%:h')`, or `expand('%:p:h')` to have an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

`getcwd()`, so the command you want would be `:NERDTreeToggle getcwd()`.

You just exchanged one character. `pwd` means print working directory. `cwd` means current working directory. That's why the function name is a bit different.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. As written in the linked answer, it is `getcwd()` but still did not work...

Comment: But then the command works, the trouble is using it on the mapping?